# Append objects in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I store objects in local storage with the following:

```
 localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I want to add multiple instances of obj every one second, giving a time key. How can I append obj instead of change it every time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = 
{
 'product-name': itemContainer.find('h2.product-name a').text(),
 'product-image': itemContainer.find('div.product-image img').attr('src'),
 'product-price': itemContainer.find('span.product-price').text()
};

 oldItems.push(newItem);

 localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
```

You may also want to consider using an object instead of an array and use the product name as the key. This will prevent duplicate entries showing up in LocalStorage.

Comment: How can i check is full?? Basically, tracking when there is not enough memory to store another object and to begin shift the first objects.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: oldItems.push is not a function @JoseRamon I'm getting this error

Answer (score 8):

Basically you have to retrieve the object, add your value and then write it back to `localStorage`.

```
var obj = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('obj') ) || {};
obj[ timestamp ] = 'newvalue';
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: Yeah exactly what i want. Thanks!!

Comment: This is nice and concise, but I think the first part should be `var obj = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('obj') ) || {};` to first get the existing item from localStorage.

Answer (score 4):

There are two options:

1. Instead of storing the object store a list/map of objects, then to add an element just first do the `getItem`, then push/set the new element, then use `setItem`.
2. Store the objects using the date as the key (e.g. `localStorage.setItem('obj:' + x.time, x)`) and the use `for (x in localStorage) {...}` to find all the keys.

Comment: On a larger data-set this sounds like the better option.

Answer (score 3):

```
function store() 
{
    var person=new Object();
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    person.firstname="John";
    person.lastname="Doe";
    person.age=50;
    person.eyecolor="blue";
    localStorage.setObj("temp", person);
    var obj=localStorage.getObj("temp");
    for(var i in obj)
    alert(i+"--"+obj[i]);
}
Storage.prototype.setObj = function(key, obj) {
     return this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj))
}
Storage.prototype.getObj = function(key) {
     return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key))
}
```